# What is the Boxing Hover/Wave Hand Technique called?

Tags: technique, mixed-martial-arts, boxing, muay-thai, kung-fu

What is the official terminology for boxing jab hover called? See video below. This is where the boxer hovers/waves his hand in a circle to confuse opponent, in attempts to jab punch. I tried google searching for boxing "hover", but did not see anymore resources.

https://youtu.be/wnzBnwBPcU4?t=172

Wanted to find the official name/terminology, so I can look into further and its uses, etc. Open to Kung fu/Karate terminology also, if its not really seen in boxing.

[image]

Comment: No idea, but I call it 'pawing'. As in, 'the bear pawed at his prey' : )  Some notable boxing journalists use the same term.

Comment: hi @Futilitarian that seems to be it, feel free to write as answer, and I can send points, https://youtu.be/iz8TN3yAh50?t=121.   https://forums.sherdog.com/threads/pawing-jab.2266071/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term is "Pawing jab".

Here's an analysis of how [Thomas "The Hitman" Hearns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iz8TN3yAh50) used it to great effect as a measuring stick, a 'stiff-arm', to manipulate line-of-sight, and to set up his devastating right.

Comment: Side note, using it as a "stiff-arm" in boxing is technically the violation of "posting" when you're within striking range and can get you penalized.

Comment: @MacacoBranco. True. The video acknowledges this and provides a good example of how some rules can be bent in boxing without significant consequence. There is so much money involved, most referees will feel an enormous amount of pressure to not allow a series of (relatively) minor transgressions to determine the outcome of a fight, even if they should technically result in disqualification. If there hasn't been already, a question re. 'dirty boxing' tactics might be interesting.